# how to pass a date/time reference in a call to a basic duckling server?

Tags: wit.ai, duckling

Any pointers on how to pass a date/time reference to a basic, vanilla duckling server?

I'm using duckling for parsing text. When looking for time expressions, I need to pass in a *reference date/time*.

A reference date/time gives me an anchor for expressions like "yesterday" and "today."

*e.g.*

reference date = April 1, 2018 => "1 week ago" = March 25, 2018.

reference time = April 1, 2018, 3pm => "in 8 hours" = April 1, 2018, 11pm

The [duckling repo site](https://github.com/facebookincubator/duckling) has instructions on how to make a basic server run locally, that you can then call with

```
curl -XPOST http://0.0.0.0:8000/parse --data 'locale=en_GB&text=tomorrow at eight'
```

but not many more examples are provided that I could find. I can see in [ExampleMain.hs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/duckling/blob/master/exe/ExampleMain.hs) that `dims` and `lang` are also options as parameters along `text` and `locale`, but nothing on reference date.

Comment: any updates on this? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
curl -XPOST http://0.0.0.0:8000/parse --data 'locale=en_GB&text=tomorrow at eight&reftime=<unix epoch in millisecond>'
```

Reference:

https://github.com/facebook/duckling/issues/166